# How to delay rigid body animation without preventing object from rotate?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have a cube located 3m above the floor. I keyframed location and rotation at frame 0. Then I rotate it and keyframed rotation at frame 130. Finally, I added rigid body (active) to the cube and (passive) to the floor.

I'd like the rigid body animation to begin at frame 55, but when I try the different methods of delay (rigid body cache frames, animated or Dynamic checked/unchecked...), my cube doesn't rotate anymore between frame 0 and 55, or with rigid body cache (frame55 to 130), the cube rotate and stops abruptly at frame 55. I would like my cube keeps a kind of rotation force when it falls down.

Hope you understand what I want to do. Thanks for reading ;)

Comment: Have your tried animating it?

Comment: What do you mean by animating it?

Comment: Under the dynamic check box you can press the animated check box. As long as it is checked it will do what was keyframed. When it is unchecked it will move normally.

Comment: Yes, i tried that. When I preview, it works, but when I render: at frame 54, the cube is up and at frame 55, the cube is down :/

Comment: I retried this method and it works. I don't know why it didn't work first time I tried, there was probably a bug :/ Thank you for your answer Yohello 1, finally it is the right one ;)